How to extract data between {} when there might be sub-brackets from other TeX macros?
I have a file that has a TeX macro like this:
\summary{here is some text}{more}{yet more}{yet even more text}{some more}{and yet more}

I need to extra from each line the contents with the first {} pair, second {} pair, etc. separately. In a normal situation, I would simply use:
variablea=`echo "\summary{here is some text}{more}{yet more}{yet even more text}{some more}{and yet more}" | awk -F'{' '{ print $2 }' | awk -F'}' '{ print $1 }'`

The problem I am facing is that any of the {} pairs can contain more TeX macros, like \quote{}, \quotation{}, \citation{}{}, etc. Some with one {} some with two {}{}, etc. and further data inside.
variablea=`echo "\summary{here is some \quotation{text}}{more}{yet more}{yet even more text}{some more}{and yet more}" | awk -F'{' '{ print $2 }' | awk -F'}' '{ print $1 }'`

Notice if I use the above code, because it had a \quotation{text} inside the first {} pair, it didn't print the entire contents of the first {} of \summary but got confused and processed the text inside.
To make things even worse, there could be macros inside macros inside macros:
here is some \quotation{text that is \index{useful}}

How can I extract the data from each {} pair, keeping the data inside in-tact, without it confusing other {'s and }'s belonging to other macros?

Setting out to write a TeX parser in Awk may be more ambitious than wise.

Did you consider redefining the summary command to print the arguments with a convenient separator, and then use latex to do the parsing?

perl -lane 'while (/\{((?:[^{}]++|(?R))*)\}/g) {print $1}'

Given this input file:
$ cat file
\summary{here is some \quotation{text that is \index{useful}}}{more}{yet more}{yet even more text}{some more}{and yet more}

This, using any POSIX awk, will produce the output I think you want:
$ cat tst.awk
{
    str = $0
    while ( match(str, /[{}]/) ) {
        char = substr(str, RSTART, 1)
        if ( char == "{" ) {
            depth++
        }
        if ( depth ) {
            out = out substr(str, 1, RSTART)
            if ( (char == "}") && (--depth == 0) ) {
                gsub(/^[^{}]*\{|}$/, "", out)
                print out
                out = ""
            }
        }
        str = substr(str, RSTART+1)
    }
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
here is some \quotation{text that is \index{useful}}
more
yet more
yet even more text
some more
and yet more

That assumes you don't have any { or } in your input that are escaped in some way and so should be ignored when counting them.

I would harness GNU AWK to remove non top-level brackets following way
echo "\summary{here is some \quotation{text}}{more}{yet more}{yet even more text}{some more}{and yet more}" | awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";ORS=""}{gsub(/\\[a-z]*/,"");for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){depth+=($i=="{");depth-=($i=="}");if($i=="{"&&depth==1||$i=="}"&&depth==0||$i!="{"&&$i!="}"){print $i}}}END{print "\n"}'

gives output
{here is some text}{more}{yet more}{yet even more text}{some more}{and yet more}

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that each character should be treated as field and it should not append anything when using print .I remove \summary and \quotation and similar using gsub, then I use for loop over character, for each step I compute depth after said character, where { increase depth by 1, whilst } decrease depth by 1. Based on character and depth I determine if it should be printed, I print where at least 1 of following holds

{ character at depth 1
} character at depth 0
any character which is not { and is not }

After all this in done I print newline character. This way output is not-nested structure with which you can deal yourself.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
